# How do i do a onclick who reload 3 different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, refresh

How can I reload 3 JavaScript datecodes every time I press a image?

I don't want the whole paga to refresh just some divs, can this be done?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: You might want to explain what a 'javascript datecode' is.

Answer (score 0):

You might be searching for something like jquery's find:

http://api.jquery.com/find/

You can 'find' all the divs you want to reload and do something with them when the image is clicked.

Comment: But how do I do it with divs?